# Circle CI and Behat

Tags: symfony, curl, behat, circleci

Helo i have a problem with running behat test on circle ci. When i try to run them on my local everything works fine.

Here is a screen: https://www.dropbox.com/s/f27tfxdm1zxst8h/Screenshot%202016-11-17%2014.33.54.png?dl=0

and here is my circle.yml:

```
machine:
  timezone:
    Europe/Prague
  php:
    version: 7.0.7

dependencies:
  pre:
    - cp $HOME/$CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME/app/config/parameters.yml.circle.dist $HOME/$CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME/app/config/parameters.yml

database:
  override:
    - php app/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --no-interaction

test:
  override:
    - php bin/behat
```

Thanks for help

### UPDATE

circle.yml

```
machine:
  timezone:
    Europe/Prague
  php:
    version: 7.0.7

dependencies:
  pre:
    - cp $HOME/$CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME/app/config/parameters.yml.circle.dist $HOME/$CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME/app/config/parameters.yml

  post:
    - sudo cp $HOME/$CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME/app/config/mywebsite.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available
    - sudo a2ensite mywebsite.conf
    - sudo rm /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load
    - sudo service apache2 restart

database:
  override:
    - php app/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --no-interaction -e=test

test:
  override:
    - php bin/behat
```

mywebsite.conf

```
Listen 8080

<VirtualHost *:8080>
  LoadModule php7_module /opt/circleci/php/7.0.7/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.so

  DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/my_project/web
  ServerName mywebsite.com
  <FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
  </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

And of course now i'm trying to connect to url mywebsite.com but response is still: **cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: mywebsite.com (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) (GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException)**

Comment: Do you have a server started on the same machine? seems it didn't found any local server, If you have a remote server you should configure wd_host in your behat yml config file.

Comment: Here is my [behat.yml](http://pastebin.com/C2NVk9FZ). Test should ask local server not remote. I saw some wd_host config but only for mink or selenium. Not for symfony2extension.

Comment: Similar to what I experienced https://discuss.circleci.com/t/drupal-8-behat-apache-returns-403/12806. Did you in the meanwhile found a fix or workaround you are happy with?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you and finally got it running. The mere Apache config sample in the Circle docs will never work. For me the following did work in the end:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot /home/circleci/drupal-circleci-behat/web
    ServerName drupal-circleci-behat.localhost

    <Directory /home/circleci/drupal-circleci-behat/web >
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Also I had added the domain to the host file via `config.yml`:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/php:7.1-apache-node-browsers

    working_directory: ~/drupal-circleci-behat

    steps:
      - checkout

      - run:
          name: Apache
          command: |
            sudo cp .circleci/drupal-circleci-behat.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/drupal-circleci-behat.conf
            sudo a2ensite drupal-circleci-behat
            sudo service apache2 start
            echo 127.0.0.1 drupal-circleci-behat.localhost | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
            cat /etc/hosts
            curl drupal-circleci-behat.localhost

      - run:
          name: Other stuff ...
          command: |
            ...
```

Working sample repo here: https://github.com/leymannx/drupal-circleci-behat